# How to avoid "message rejected with no message-id" when using Indy smtp

Tags: smtp, delphi-xe5, indy10

On rare occasions my emails bounce back with the message:

Remote host said: 550-RFC2822 says that all mail SHOULD have a Message-ID header.
550 Most messages without it are spam, so your mail has been rejected.

I've tried setting a message-id header using:

```
IdMessage1.Headers.Values['Message-ID'] := id;
```

In this case id is a string in the format xxxxx at mydomain.  However either that's not how to set a message-id header, or it's getting stripped by my smtp server (hosted by my isp.)   I've noticed that emails sent from Outlook do get a message-id and they aren't stripped.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to supply the message-id header so it doesn't get stripped?  Are there other headers that I should include as well?  I've also emailed my isp in case it's a setting on their end but Outlook must do it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide a custom header when *sending* or *saving* an email, you have to use the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property instead. The `TIdMessage.Headers` property is used when *receiving* or *loading* an email.

`TIdMessage` has a `MsgId` property that you can use instead.  However, when *sending* an email, the `MsgId` property value is ignored, so you have to resort to `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` to send a custom `Message-ID` header.  The `TIdMessage.MsgId` value is NOT ignored with *saving* an email, though.

---

**EDIT:**

As a followup for this - `TIdMessage` has now been updated with logic changes in how it handles the "Message-ID" and "In-Reply-To" headers:

https://www.indyproject.org/2016/09/12/logic-changes-in-tidmessage-regarding-message-id-and-in-reply-to-headers/

In a nutshell, the `TIdMessage.MsgId` property now generates a "Message-ID" header when creating a new email (you do not need to use the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property anymore, though you still can if needed), and the "In-Reply-To" header is no longer auto-generated using the current "Message-ID" header when the `TIdMessage.InReplyTo` property is blank.

Comment: Remy, thanks for the info.  I've now set message-id using extra headers and it appears to work, however I also get In-Reply-To: set to the same value.  Is there any way to avoid that or does that make sense at all?

Comment: Yes, I meant `MsgId`, sorry.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: As for the `In-Reply-To` header, it is set to the same value as the `Message-ID` header if the `TIdMessage.InReplyTo` property is blank. That is hard-coded behavior, it cannot be avoided. `TIdMessage` acts on the belief that clients were never meant to generate their own message IDs, that should be the server's responsibility. That belief has been questioned over the years, but `TIdMessage` has not been updated accordingly yet.

Comment: Thanks Remy, My ISP said that they couldn't change the servers behavior (it appears it does not set a message id automatically.)  Do you think that having the extra in-reply-to header would cause an issue?  I guess I could also try to modify the indy code (though i've never looked at it.)

Comment: I modified my version of Indy to not set in-reply-to for my situation.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Original link: http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20160912.aspx